# Rails 4 app - where to put custom jQuery plugins and how to include them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to add [Raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty) to my rails 4 app, but was wondering where I need to put it. I'm assuming the [lib](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/tree/master/lib) folder just needs to be put into this path?

> vendor/assets/javascripts

And then to use the script I just do `<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.raty' %>` in my files? I want to be able to use it on multiple pages. Also, can I use the script in .erb files or only regular html? Completely new to this so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll need them on multiple pages, sometimes its easiest just to dump them in app/assets/javascripts. This will include the script on every page without the need to make an explicit call. If you want, you could put them in public/js and reference them on whatever pages require the scripts.

Comment: so just do <%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.raty' %> at the top of the pages I want to use them for and I'll be good to go?

Answer (score 7):

You can download the plugin and save it in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. Then you include it on `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery.raty
```

This way the plugin is available throughout your application. The minified version of the plugin is about 8.3Kb.

Comment: it looks like that only works for rails 3.2.3 and I'm using rails 4.0.3

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should specify the Rails version on tags of original post.